# Converting for loop to apply/lapply/sapply: column based operations

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

Let's say I have the following `for loop` code, which perfectly works:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Dir)) {
    if (is.na(Dir[i, 3]) == TRUE) {
        Dir[i, 3] = Dir[i, 5]/Dir[i, 4]
    }
}
```

What it does is checks the column elements for each row and if there is `NA`, it replaces the `NA` with a number that is obtained dividing the `5th column` element to the `4th column` element.

How can I convert this and similar `for` loops that are based on column elements to a code that uses `apply/lapply/sapply`?

Any comprehensive resources to learn more about `apply/lapply/sapply` would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Dir[ , 3] = ifelse(is.na(Dir[ , 3]), Dir[, 5]/Dir[, 4], Dir[ , 3])`

Comment: Is `Dir` a dataframe or a matrix? You probably don't even need to use anything like `apply` to get this done.

Comment: I would also recommend using column names rather than column numbers unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: `Dir` is dataframe. Wouldn't using `for` be less efficient than `apply` in these cases?

Comment: Yes, `for` is inefficient, but as baptiste's suggestion shows, you don't even need `apply`.

Comment: Not trying to be picky, but how would I write the above code using `apply`? Just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: It's a misconception that for loops should always be replaced by *apply functions; there are cases where a for loop is just as good as a *apply alternative: it can be more readable, and without noticeable slowdown. However, in many cases, thinking of the problem in a different way will suggest a vectorised solution, and that's a much better alternative.

Comment: I don't know if it was mentioned in any deleted comment, but just for your further understanding: The `is.na()` operation returns a boolean vector of `TRUE/FALSE` results. So when using `is.na()` (or any other operator of the `is.()` kind) in an `if`-statement, you do not need to clarify the desired outcome as `== TRUE`. Use `is.na()` if you want to check for the `NA == TRUE` state and `!is.na()` if you want to check for the `NA == FALSE` state. You can see it in @Marius's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `apply` here, you can do something like:

```
n_rows = 20
Dir = data.frame(
    a = sample(1:100, n_rows),
    b = sample(1:100, n_rows),
    c = sample(c(NA, 1, 2), n_rows, replace = TRUE),
    d = sample(1:100, n_rows),
    e = sample(1:100, n_rows)
)

# MARGIN = 1: apply along the rows (MARGIN = 2 for columns)
Dir$c = apply(Dir, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) {
    if (is.na(row[3])) {
        return(row[5] / row[4])
    } else {
        return(row[3])
    }
})
```

**But:** `apply` is not necessarily faster or more efficient than `for` loops. Vectorized code like baptiste's suggestion

```
Dir[ , 3] = ifelse(is.na(Dir[ , 3]), Dir[, 5]/Dir[, 4], Dir[ , 3])
```

is usually faster than both, once your data is big enough for the differences to matter, and is less work to write with less typing required once you've got your head around how it works.